# Copying variables in java

Tags: java

I am trying to copy variables of the same class type

```
FUNCTION[] funcs;
FUNCTION[] orphelines;
```

as follows

```
orphelines[nb_orphelines]=funcs[numero];
```

Is `=` right for this task? I get a `NullPointer` error....

Comment: Then either `orphelines` or `funcs` (or both) is `null`. But only if you post a MCVE someone can give a definite answer.

Comment: Sure, orphelines[nb_orphelines] is null. That's the idea: to pass funcs[numero] to orphelines[nb_orphelines], taking into account that FUNCTION[] holds inner functions.

Comment: No, `orphelines` is `null`, not `orphelines[nb_orphelines]`. In other words, there is no array at all. Somewhere you need to create the array, for example : `orphelines = new orphelines[100];`

Comment: You have to make a distinction between the array (as a container) and the elements stored in it. You must first create _the container_ (i.e. by calling `orphelines = new orphelines[funcs.length];` or similar). Then you can start populating it.